# Difference between OPEN_ALWAYS and CREATE_ALWAYS in CreateFile() of Windows API

Tags: c, windows, createfile

Can anyone explain what the difference is between the creation dispositions `OPEN_ALWAYS` and `CREATE_ALWAYS` of the [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) function of the windows API?

To me it seems that they both simply 'create the file if it does not already exist'.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`CREATE_ALWAYS` also truncates the contents if the file already exists. On the other hand, `OPEN_ALWAYS` will not clobber an already existing file.

Here's how the different values work in tabular form:

```
                         |                    When the file...
This argument:           |             Exists            Does not exist
-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
CREATE_ALWAYS            |            Truncates             Creates
CREATE_NEW         +-----------+        Fails               Creates
OPEN_ALWAYS     ===| does this |===>    Opens               Creates
OPEN_EXISTING      +-----------+        Opens                Fails
TRUNCATE_EXISTING        |            Truncates              Fails
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was hoping - funny that the documentation is so vaguely formulated. Thanks.

Comment: Nice table. Some random thoughts: if the file exists there are 3 outcomes: _Truncates, Fails, Opens_; if the file does not exist there are 2 outcomes: _Creates, Fails_. So 3*2 = 6 different behaviours. Since the _Fails/Fails_ is totally useless, only 5 possibilities remains, and here they are!

Comment: Also what is important to add to that table is what happens to the [file pointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542(v=vs.85).aspx) when existing file is opened (when `OPEN_ALWAYS` or `OPEN_EXISTING` is specified.) In both cases the file pointer will point to the beginning of the file. So, if you then start writing into that file, it will overwrite the beginning of the file and **will not** append it to the end of file. To change that use `SetFilePointerEx` function with `FILE_END` flag before writing.

Comment: @ahmd0 Where `WriteFile`s ends up actually depends on the access mask, if you only ask for file-append it will write to the end of the file on NT.